# Running PHP in shell line gives issues

Tags: php, shell

Anytime I try to run a PHP file (such as one I'm going to be using for a cron task) I get the following errors:

```
[root@server1 ~]# php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr//20100525/apc.so' -        /usr//20100525/apc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr//20100525/curl.so' - /usr//20100525/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr//20100525/fileinfo.so' - /usr//20100525/fileinfo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr//20100525/imap.so' - /usr//20100525/imap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr//20100525/json.so' - /usr//20100525/json.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr//20100525/mcrypt.so' - /usr//20100525/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr//20100525/mysqli.so' - /usr//20100525/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr//20100525/phar.so' - /usr//20100525/phar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr//20100525/sqlite3.so' - /usr//20100525/sqlite3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr//20100525/wddx.so' - /usr//20100525/wddx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr//20100525/zip.so' - /usr//20100525/zip.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the fact it's trying to load the extensions from `/usr//20100525` but I'm not sure where the extensions are

EDIT:

There must have been something wrong in one of my configurations somewhere for PHP. I reinstalled PHP and everything seems to be working how it should now!

Comment: What does `locate /curl.so` give you?

Comment: `/usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so`
Now how do you change where modules load from? And what is really weird is it works fine when it's a normal PHP page :s

Answer (score 0):

You need to use symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/php/modules /usr/20100525
```

Comment: Still gives the same message, but if i navigate to /usr/20100525 it and run ls it does give me all the modules

Comment: @user1247434 If you copied line try again (because I had typo)

Comment: I noticed the typo before I copied it and fixed it first

Comment: maybe user from whom you run php doesn't have enough rights on these files?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this error so i have solved it with this way try this

I went to PHP Config, in CPanel, and restored my php.ini master file clicking on "install php.ini master file". Then it's created a file in your public_html home directory called php.ini.default I just made a backup of the old php.ini file, and renamed php.ini.default to php.ini.

After that, I went to the directories where broken WP instances were installed and renamed their own php.ini files to php.ini.back so the main php.ini file is used instead.

That's it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you edited the `extension_dir` setting in your `php.ini` file? By default it's blank, and `php` finds its extensions at the right location. You can force it by adding the line:

```
extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules"
```

You say you don't have the problem when it runs in Apache, only when it runs as script. Keep in mind that there are separate `php.init` files for each, for example:

```
$ locate /php.ini | grep ini$
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```